# вообще без понятия что делать. traceback

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вообще без понятия что делать. traceback

Comment: Прикрепляйте код и ошибки не скриншотом. А так: питон говорит что нету файла.

Comment: Для начала - учиться читать.

Answer (score 2):

Если не знаете что делать, то может ну его это программирование?
Ясно-ж написано, нет файла с именем, которые вы подсовываете в 12 строчке вашего скрипта. Нет файла с именем "0.ppm".  Что делать? Обеспечить, что-бы такой файл был.